# Can I represent or write continous density function in the following way?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $$f(x)=\cases{1 &for $0<x<1$\\0& for $x=0$\\ 0 &for $x=1$}$$Can I say f is a density function of a random variable on [0,1]. I mean to say is it correct way to write or define the continuous density at some finite points ? Is there any ambiguity to write the continuous density in this way as long as it satisfies the condition that 1. f(x)>=0 and integral of f(x) is 1.

Comment: You also need to define what happens below $x=0$  and above $x=1$. Typically, we say $f (x) = 1$ if 0 < x < 1 and $f (x) =0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you may.
The long answer:

You will find that what you propose will have functionally identical properties to
$$f(x) = 1 \ \forall x\in[0,1], \ 0 \text{ elsewhere}$$
Since in either distribution,
$$P(X=0) = \lim_{b\to^+ 0} F(b) - F(0) = 0$$
$$P(X=1) = \lim_{b\to^- 1} F(1) - F(b) = 0$$